# Removing rows in an excel worksheet if duplicate is found in another worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, microsoft-excel-2016

I have two worksheets: "compiled" and "firstpickup". What I'm looking to do is delete rows in the sheet "firstpickup" if the value in column A can also be found in column A of "compiled". "compiled" is 42,000 rows and "firstpickup" is 21,000, so I'd like to be able to just run the macro and have it end after going through all the data.

Here are some options I tried based on cursory Google searches:

```
 Sub RemoveDuplicates()
    Dim rCrit As Range 'Range To Search For Duplicates
    Dim rFilt As Range 'Range To Remove Duplicates
    Dim lLoop As Long

    Set rCrit = Worksheets("compiled").Range("A1", Worksheets("compiled").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    Set rFilt = Worksheets("firstpickup").Range("A1", Worksheets("firstpickup").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

    For lLoop = rCrit.Rows.Count To 2 Step -1
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rCrit, rFilt(lLoop).Value) > 0 Then
            Worksheets("firstpickup").Rows(lLoop).Delete shift:=xlUp
        End If
    Next lLoop
End Sub
```

This sub kept not finding matches in the "if" function, so it never deleted any rows, even for rows which I knew had duplicates.

```
Sub Removeduplicates()

Dim Row As Long
Dim FoundDup As Range

Sheets("compiled").Select

For Row = Range("A24031").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1

Set FoundDup = Sheets("compiled").Range("A:A").Find(Cells(Row, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

If Not FoundDup Is Nothing Then
    Cells(Row, 1).EntireRow.Delete
End If

Next Row

End Sub
```

This sub also wasn't successful; after the "For" query, the debugger would skip to "end sub".

Any help at all, either reworking my previous attempts or helping me with a different solution, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For your second part, are you sure `Range("A24031").End(xlUp).Row` returns a value greater than 2?  Maybe explicitly put the worksheet before that - `Worksheets("compiled").Range(...)...`?

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this VBA code, will help you to Delete Rows from Sheet `Firstpickup`, *if Values in Column A will match with values in Column A* of `Complied Sheet`.**

```
Sub DeleRows()
Dim LR As Long, i As Long
With Sheets("Firstpickup")
LR = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = LR To 1 Step -1
    If IsNumeric(Application.Match(.Range("A" & i).Value, Sheets("Complied").Columns("A"), 0)) Then .Rows(i).Delete
Next i
End With
End Sub
```